# Integers in cells problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

All the whole numbers $1-9$ are placed in the $9$ triangular cells. A negative sign is placed in front of some numbers. The letters $A-F$ are products of $3$ or $5$ of the numbers. Find all possible solutions.

$A= 320$

$B= 162$

$C= 6048$

$D= -60$

$E= 756$

$F= -240$

[image]

Comment: What have you done on the subject ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).